# Returning a substring within given HTML tags in a Row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring

I've below `3 rows` in a `table` -

```
1. <p><strong>By Dr. Mercola</strong></p>  <blockquote>  <p>In an interview with ElectromagneticHealth.org
2. <p><strong>By Barbara Loe Fisher</strong></p>  <blockquote>   <p>Here we are in the winter of 2015, and 
3. <p><strong>By Gary Ruskin<br>  Co-Founder and Executive Director, U.S. Right to Know</strong></p>  <blockquote>   <p>U.S. Right to Know
```

From the above rows i want to `fetch` a `substring` and want a `result` as below -

```
Dr. Mercola
Barbara Loe Fisher 
Gary Ruskin
```

For this i have written below query-

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<p><strong>By', FormattedBody, -1)=1 THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(FormattedBody as nvarchar(max)),CHARINDEX('</strong>', FormattedBody)-1),'<p><strong>By',''))    
 ELSE 'Dr.Mercola' END as Name
```

The above `query` returns the expected `output` for the `first 2 rows`, but not for the `third row`. It returns `Gary Ruskin<br>  Co-Founder and Executive Director, U.S. Right to Know`

Please let me know what additional changes should be made to the `query` to get `expected results`. Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below query and working properly for each case-

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<p><strong>By', FormattedBody, -1)=1 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CAST(FormattedBody as varchar(max)),'<p><strong>By ',''),0,CHARINDEX('<',REPLACE(cast(FormattedBody as varchar(max)),'<p><strong>By ','')))) 
 ELSE 'Dr.Mercola' END as Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matching is looking for `</strong>` to end the name.

However, the examples suggest that `<` is sufficient for this purpose.  It is hard to imagine a person's name with this character, so it seems safe to use that.

So, you can try:

```
(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<p><strong>By', FormattedBody, -1) = 1
      THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(FormattedBody as nvarchar(max)), CHARINDEX('<', FormattedBody) - 1, 12), '<p><strong>By', ''))    
      ELSE 'Dr.Mercola'
 END) as Name
```

Comment: returns `NULL` for every row which is obvious as `<` character appeared in the 1st place..

Comment: @PranavBilurkar . . . Just add an additional argument to the `CHARINDEX()` so it starts the search later in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(col,'<p><strong>By ',''),0,CHARINDEX('<',REPLACE(col,'<p><strong>By ','')))
FROM (VALUES
('<p><strong>By Dr. Mercola</strong></p>  <blockquote>  <p>In an interview with ElectromagneticHealth.org'),
('<p><strong>By Barbara Loe Fisher</strong></p>  <blockquote>   <p>Here we are in the winter of 2015, and '),
('<p><strong>By Gary Ruskin<br>  Co-Founder and Executive Director, U.S. Right to Know</strong></p>  <blockquote>   <p>U.S. Right to Know')
) as t (col)
```

Will give you:

```
Dr. Mercola
Barbara Loe Fisher
Gary Ruskin
```